# Jquery, hide divs in div blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide the divs except the first one in each of the div blocks with a unique class name. I am doing this because I have multiple carousels and I am shifting each one except the first one off the screen except the first div. This works great for a single carousel but when I introduce multiple ones, it hides all the divs except the first one.

original code for single carousel was:

```
$("div.hero-featureSwap:not(:first)").css({
    "left" : "2000px"
});
```

but now I want to show the first "hero-featureSwap" of each carousel. Is there a hack around this?

Comment: Use the parent container, then, $.each, then perform this.

Comment: you might want to remove the `java` tag :P

Comment: unless we know how the html look likes, the answer will be shooting in darkness. Could you please post the html, not full, but only the significant ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing your structure might be something like this -

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
</div>
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
</div>
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
    <div class="carousel-child"></div>
</div>
```

Then this is how I would have done this -

```
$("div.carousel").each(function(){
    $(this).find("div.carousel-child:not(:first)").css({
        "left" : "2000px"
    });
});
```

Please make necessary class name changes according to your structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$("div.hero-featureSwap").find('div:gt(0)').hide();
```

**To hide**. To move all other divs except the first the page, your code is just fine, or:

```
$("div.hero-featureSwap:gt(0)").css({
    "left" : "2000px"
});
```